# compiling rpm 4.11 for RHEL5

Tags: rhel, rpm

I am trying to compile rpm 4.11.2 on RHEL 5 machine. When I do `./configure` it gives error

```
    .
    .
    checking for nspr.h... yes
    checking nss.h usability... yes
    checking nss.h presence... yes
    checking for nss.h... yes
    checking sechash.h usability... yes
    checking sechash.h presence... yes
    checking for sechash.h... yes
    checking for VFY_VerifyDigestDirect in -lnss3... no
    configure: error: required NSS library 'nss3' missing or too old
```

The exact command for `./configure` is

```
   ./configure --prefix=$PWD/exe CPPFLAGS='-I/export/stapas/nss-3.23/nspr/exe/include/nspr -I/export/stapas/nss-3.23/dist/public/nss' LDFLAGS='-L/export/stapas/nss-3.23/nss/lib /nss/Linux2.6_x86_cc_glibc_PTH_DBG.OBJ'
```

Though libnss3.so is present in `/usr/lib` & `/usr/lib64` we can see in above LDFLAGS option I am overiding it. Struggling for many days. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error says it: "missing **or too old**". Probably some symbols are missing in your library nss. You can check this using:

```
nm <path-to-libnss3> | grep VFY_VerifyDigestDirect
```

Now there are two possibilities:

1. *VFY_VerifyDigestDirect* is found; that means the linker doesn't find your nss3 library after all
2. *VFY_VerifyDigestDirect* is not found; thus your libnss3 is too old. Either install a more recent libnss3; either try to rebuild an older version of *rpm*.

Comment: VFY_VerifyDigestDirect  is found which below result shows the result of your command:    /export/stapas/nss-3.23/nss/lib/nss/Linux2.6_x86_cc_glibc_PTH_DBG.OBJ/libnss3.so | grep VFY_VerifyDigestDirect
000000000002de9c T VFY_VerifyDigestDirect`. Why linker is not able to find this new library even after providing through LDFLAGS ?

Comment: You can either dig into the configure script to search which variables you should set (very little experience with that). Or you create symbolic links in /usr/lib pointing to your libraries; that will always work!

Comment: or you export LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the location of your library; that might work as well...

Comment: Already tried. I tried even renaming old library and putting new library at that place. No use.